# How to solve this recursion equation T (n) = √2T(n/2) + log n using master theorem?

Tags: recurrence, master-theorem

I know it can be solved with master method but how ? please help ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is correct:

```
a = sqrt(2) 
b = 2
f(n) = log n
log(b) a = log (2) sqrt(2) = 1/2

log n in O[n^(1/2)]
```

so the runtime of finding the logarithm of a number n is in O{n^(1/2)}  (however the Master Theorem can not be applied here)

The solution is in following threads:[Solving master theorem with log n: T(n) = 2T(n/4) + log n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987299/solving-master-theorem-with-log-n-tn-2tn-4-log-n)

*Overall, we see that your recurrence is O(n1/2) and Ω(n1/2) by upper- and lower-bounding your recurrence by larger and smaller recurrences. Therefore, even though the Master Theorem doesn't apply here, you can still use the Master Theorem to claim that the runtime will be Θ(n1/2).*

[Master's theorem with f(n)=log n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735576/masters-theorem-with-fn-log-n)

*Usually, f(n) must be polynomial for the master theorem to apply - it doesn't apply for all functions. However, there is a limited "fourth case" for the master theorem, which allows it to apply to polylogarithmic functions.*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 0):

Ralf is not correct by telling you that you can't [apply masters theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). [image]

The only constrains here is that `a >=1` and `b >= 1`, a, b can be irrational and f(n) can be anything.

`Log2(sqrt(2)) is 1/2`, which puts you in the first case and your solution is `O(n^0.5)`.